# Extract Base64 encoded WAV from JSON object

Tags: c#, json, base64

Creating a .Net 3.5 assembly that is making a call to PHP server. Return value a JSON object. The JSON object has a Base64 encoded WAV file (see below). Trying to use Newtonsoft.Json to get the WAV converted from "value". Spent 8 hours trying...

here is the code I have tried

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
string json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
//JObject jo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

This is where I get stuck. Error reads:

***"Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \". Path 'result.value', line 1, position 3449."***

Almost like the string is too long...

Have not even gotten to the Base64 convert code I sourced off the internet that needs to be tweaked

```
char[] base64CharArray;
inFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputFileName,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
base64CharArray = new char[inFile.BaseStream.Length];
inFile.Read(base64CharArray, 0, (int)inFile.BaseStream.Length);
base64String = new string(base64CharArray);
```

Solution is to go live first thing Monday...

Comment: First, are you having trouble getting the base64 string out of the JSON, or having trouble converting the base64 string to a wav file? Second, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Jason tried getting the base64 string out of the JSON. Have not even got to the base64 to wav convert. I used this to try and help me: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585500/deserialize-dicionary-with-json-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391209/deserialize-json-base64-binary-in-net-using-datacontractjsonserializer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126242/using-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-to-deserialize-json-to-a-c-sharp-poco-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work fine. Probably not the most efficient solution though. don't forget to close your streams though, since they implement `IDisposable`.
I'm using `WebClient` here, but it doesn't really makes a difference. I think that `HttpWebRequest` is redundant in this case.

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://waps.repli-con.com/services/ivrservices/getUserNameRecording/10000");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            JToken token = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd().ToString());

            string base64string = token.SelectToken("result").SelectToken("value").ToString();
            Byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.wav", b);   
            stream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks RAS... I never saw any examples that used JToken.